# Firebase remove+limited query caching bug?

Tags: firebase

If I read a value from Firebase and then remove it, a subsequent limited read (e.g. dataRef.limit(10).once("value") ) will still see the removed value.

If I do an unlimited read, then I won't see the removed value, and a subsequent limited read will also no longer see the removed value.

```
var gFirebase = new Firebase("https://brianshmrian.firebaseio.com/");

function CreateValue()
{
    gFirebase.child("TestBug/Key").set("Value");
}

function ReadValue(limit)
{
    var dataRef = gFirebase.child("TestBug");
    if (limit)
        dataRef = dataRef.limit(10);

    dataRef.once("value",function(snapshot)
    {
        alert((limit?"Limited read\n":"Normal read\n") + snapshot.val());
    });
}

function RemoveValue()
{
    gFirebase.child("TestBug/Key").remove();
}
```

In this example code, if I do a CreateValue(), then a ReadValue(), then a RemoveValue(), then a ReadValue(true), the object will still be reported to me in the last ReadValue().  However, if I do a ReadValue(false), I'll no longer see the value, and a subsequent ReadValue(true) will not see the value either.

See here to try it for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/brianshmrian/5WWR6/

So is this a bug?  Or am I making a mistake?

**EDIT**

Ok, that seems like a not too painful workaround. The code below solves my problem for now:

```
// Need to do this before the remove to avoid caching problem
dataRef.on("value", function(snapshot)
{
    setTimeout(function() { dataRef.off(); }, 3000);
});

dataRef.remove();
```

Comment: There is a bug in this type of code that we are aware of. It's on our internal tracker and we should have a fix out later next week. Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Oh, it's not a big problem.  Thanks for the quick response and also thanks for your cool service!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find any issues with the code. There is always the gotcha that locally cached data is returned synchronously, but I don't see that as an issue here; there's no way for the read to be getting called before the remove has completed. It looks like a pretty straightforward bug.

I was able to circumvent the behavior by setting up the `limit(10).on('value')` before calling the add/delete operations. So I think that if you establish your query ref first, you'll be okay.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/6wQFF/2/ (the pre tag is set up on load)